finding and setting an element in a double-dimensioned array
I'm tying to increment the counter for each tag in a collecton of listings as I process them.
I've got a JSON object like this:
var jsonListings = [
    {
        "img":      "2521",
        "text":     "Alice",
        "tags":     ["structure"]
    },{
        "img":      "2522",
        "text":     "Bob",
        "tags":     ["landscape","FRAMED"]
    },{
        "img":      "2523",
        "text":     "Charlie",
        "tags":     ["structure","MATTED"]
    }
];

I start my tag array with a few I want up front, so:
var taglist = new Array(
    ["ALL",0],
    ["FRAMED",0],
    ["MATTED",0]
);

then I iterate through the data, adding new tags only if needed, but always iterating the count:
$.each(jsonListings, function(i,v) {

        $.each(v.tags, function(i,val){
            if (!taglist.includes(val)){
                // taglist.push(val,0);             
            }
        });
});

Ideally, my taglist will look like this:
    ["ALL", 3],
    ["FRAMED",1],
    ["MATTED",1],
    ["structure",2],
    ["landscape",1]

But it's the commented line where I'm stumped.
(Backstory: Version one was just a simple array, with no counters, so my taglist looked like this:
    ["ALL","FRAMED","MATTED","structure","landscape"]

and that worked fine. Now that I'm adding a counter, it got real complex real fast.)
The pseudocode would be
objTagList = ["ALL",0],["FRAMED",0],["MATTED",0]

for each objListing in objJsonListings:
    for each arrTag in arrTags:
        if objTaglist does NOT include arrTag: // new tag for taglist
            objTagList.push([arrTag,1]) // add new tag
        else
            find arrTag[0] in objTagList: increment arrTag[1] by one

It's that last line that has me stumped.
I want to find the subitem in the parent array whose first element [0] equals the tag I have, so I can increment the second element [1].

How about utilizing a Map:


const jsonListings = [
    { "img": "2521", "text": "Alice", "tags": ["structure"] },
    { "img": "2522", "text": "Bob", "tags": ["landscape", "FRAMED"] },
    { "img": "2523", "text": "Charlie", "tags": ["structure", "MATTED"] }
];
const initialTags = [["ALL", 0], ["FRAMED", 0], ["MATTED", 0]];
const countByTag = new Map(initialTags);
jsonListings.forEach((listing) => {
    listing.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        countByTag.set(tag, (countByTag.get(tag) || 0) + 1);
    });
    countByTag.set("ALL", (countByTag.get("ALL") || 0) + 1);
});
const tagAndCounts = Array.from(countByTag);
console.log(tagAndCounts);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




Thank you. Works like a charm. I once tried maps. Still a mystery.
